# using legrand-orange-book template with non-english language

Tags: xetex

I am trying to write a persian book using http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book template. 
I have included xepersian package. My first problem is that when I wirte persian words inside `\section{...}` words did not show up in generated pdf.
I tried changing `\usepackage[english]{babel}` to `\usepackage[farsi,arabic,english]{babel}` but it gives me `Encoding scheme LAE' unknown. ...ntencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\alefhamza}}` & `Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding LAE. ^^I\caption{...}` & other errors like this. How could I used this template to write persian without above problems.
and last I want latex to generate labels for chapter and figures in persian instead of default chapter 1, 2 and ...
what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: We can't use `babel` with xetex , since you are using `xepersian` to write persian   you should delete packages `babel` , `inputenc` , `fontenc`.